# Google Analytics Custom Campaigns not reporting Revenue

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk, enhanced-ecommerce

I have created custom campaigns and completed standard ecommerce transactions with the UTM parameters set in the URL when the user hits the site initially, but my campaigns continue to say 0 revenue. My transactions are showing in Google Analytics, but they are not being attributed to the campaign. Can I have some help on the potential holes in my setup? Any insight will help.

[Ecommerce Product and Revenue expected on the Campaigns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVqbd.png)

[Campaigns that have no Revenue attributed to them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uro01.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue, cache. I have done hard refreshes before every test, but I went into Chrome tools and clear EVERYTHING. Cookie, cache, everything. And Cross-Domain tracking for Custom Campaigns started working! For reference here are the scripts for the two sites:

```
Site 1:

ga('create','UA-xxxxxxx-x'','auto', { 'allowLinker': true });
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['site2.com']);
ga('require','ecommerce','ecommerce.js');
ga('send','pageview');

Site2:

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x', 'auto', { 'name': 'client', 'allowLinker': true });
ga('client.require', 'linker');
ga('client.linker:autoLink', ['site1.com']);
ga('client.require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
ga('client.send', 'pageview');
```

Also, I added site1.com and site2.com to the Referral Exclusion List in GA and the UA key for site 1 and site 2 are the same.